# Suffixes for historical figures

Tags: history, suffixes

When it comes to historical figures, or at least famous person in the past, the suffixes like さん/様/氏 are used?
Like in 足利尊氏さん. I don't know why, but the use of suffix give me a sense of "familiarity", a sense of "closeness", as to treat the historical figure like a "living person" and not only a name.
Could be wrong though.
What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no. Historical figures are referred to by names alone. It should be the same as Mr./Mrs. etc. are not used for historical figures in English.

That said, it is possible to use suffixes (or it's imaginable for some people using them) in certain cases.  E.g., a historian might use 足利尊氏さん in explaining something on TV. This would give a sort of closeness to the figure, as you mention. Or a descent of a historical figure using 様  to show respect. On the other hand, I cannot really imagine 氏 is added to refer to a historical figure.

---

In Japanese historical context, family name+氏 (e.g. 足利氏) means the family as a whole (as a clan). It's like *the Habsburgs*, but in Western history ー家{け} is used (ハプスブルク家).

And an exception I can think of is お釈迦様{しゃかさま} to mean the Buddha/Siddartha Gautama. But this is more or less a proper name by itself.

Comment: Well, while even in the context of Buddhism Buddha isn't *strictly* a deity, he's often basically treated as one, so I think that's more where お釈迦様 is coming from

Comment: @Angelos Yeah, but normally we don't say キリスト様.

Answer (score 5):

Academic and objective texts like Wikipedia articles generally do not include any honorifics at all, regardless of whether that person is alive or not. In casual and private conversations, celebrities and athletes who are not your personal acquaintances are usually mentioned without any honorifics at all, unless you feel particularly close to them. Historical figures are mostly mentioned in contexts similar to these, so as a result, you will rarely see honorifics added to their names.

However, in principle, there is no rule that requires you to change honorifics usage based on whether someone is alive or not. In news shows and talks shows, people still commonly say [手塚治虫](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osamu_Tezuka)さん even though he passed away more than 30 years ago. While there is no strict rule, it is better to use honorifics while the person is still in the memory of many people. Familiar deities may also be called with affectionate honorifics like さん or 様 (e.g., イエス様, えびすさん, 神様, 仏様). You may see hardcore female "sengoku otaku" adding 様 to the names of warlords from 500 years ago.